# Pivot table not working due to multi-dimensionality

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe where I have data such as `domicile`, `age`, `gender`, etc.
I want to create a pivot table where it shows the state-wise gender distribution of the respondents. So I wrote the following line of code

```
table = pd.pivot_table(sample_df, values = ["gender"], index = ["domicile_state"], columns = ["gender"], aggfunc = np.count)
```

However, this shows an error that numpy doesn't have any function called count.
If I use `np.sum` instead of `np.count`, it just adds all the male/female responses end to end, something like `MaleMaleMale...`. So it's obviously doing string operations.
However, if I remove the `aggfunc`, I get an error `Grouper for 'gender' not 1-dimensional`
So basically I want a table like

```
---------------------------
domicile | gender | count |
---------------------------
A         Male      12
          female    14
B         Male      16
          Female    10
---------------------------
```

I don't have any other column with that name, So I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(sample_df['gender'], sample_df['domicile_state']).stack().reset_index()`.

Comment: or `df.groupby('domicile')['gender'].value_counts()`.

Comment: These work, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.count -> 'count'

```
pd.pivot_table(sample_df, values=["gender"], index=["domicile_state"], columns=["gender"], aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: It still shows the dimension error

Comment: That's because the gender column goes into both values ​​and index. Change one of them from `columns=['gender']` to `columns=sample_df['gender']`

Or you can use pd.crosstab as in the answer above

Comment: How do I sort these values? I mean, what should be the index in ```sort_values```

Comment: If you're talking about sorting by index, use  `sort_index` function.

Comment: No I'm talking about sorting by the frequencies

Comment: Then just run code and the problem will be solved.

Comment: But it's arranged in alphabetical order, whereas I want it in decreasing order of frequencies

Comment: What I mean is that after you run code and make pivot_table, you can see which index you can use `sort_values` for. I don't think this is a question to solve.